# Calling a frunction from another function with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, function, events, scope

this is my first time ever asking a code related question.

The problem I have is the following: I am trying to build a calculator using plain JavaScript. I have created the functions that add, subtract, etc, and I have also created a function called operate() that takes three arguments: the operation, and the two numbers that are going to be operated.

Example:

```
function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

function subtract(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

function operate(operation, num1, num2) {
    return operation(num1, num2);
}
```

Operate() works fine, but the thing is that I'm trying to call it with addEventListener and it doesn't work.

After I have my numbers and operation stored in global variables (let's say I have *add* in the *operator* variable, and *12* and *8* as *num1* and *num2*), I'm trying to do this:

```
equalButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const result = operate(operator, num1, num2);
    console.log(result);
});
```

But it says *Uncaught TypeError: operation is not a function* and it points to the function operate().

I just can't seem to see what the problem is, and I'm guessing it's going be very simple, but my mind doesn't let me resolve what's wrong.

Comment: Can you share how you're storing `add` in the `operator` variable?

Comment: I first create the global variable with  let num 1; or let operator; and then I update the values when the user clicks on the buttons.

Comment: How are you updating the value for `operator`, can you show that code?

Comment: `operatorButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    operation = e.target.value;
}));` But it's okay, I managed to accomplish what I had in mine with some if else statements. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you notice your operate function you never created an operation function so the program does not know about it so when you call the operate function you should call add and subtract function based operator passed as a parameter so it should looks like:

```
function operate(operation, num1, num2) {
   if(operation === '+')
      return add(num1,num2);
  else 
     return subtract(num1,num2);
}
```

Note that it is not an efficient solution for arithmetic operation seems you are a beginner try to achieve what you are doing first and then improve it. It should be better to create a single function and pass operator in switch case or if condition and perform operation accordingly:)

Comment: `operation` in OPs case is supposed to be a function that can be called. It isn't a string, so comparing against strings won't work...

Comment: I see, I see... What I was trying to do was this: if operation was add, operate() would look like this: operate(add, 12, 8). And then I supposed operate could run add(12,8).

Comment: Ok. I think I'll have a better time if I remove operate() completely and work only with the basic operation functions themselves. Thank you :)